# Displays: Does IPS glow affect color uniformity?

Tags: display, external-display

I just received a new LG 32UD99-W 32" IPS display, and immediately noticed that it has color uniformity issues. The left side of the display has a "yellow/green" tint, and the right side has a "red/pink" tint. This problem persists regardless of viewing angle. The tinting is clearly visible and not subtle.

I contacted the retailer and they claim that this is "IPS Glow", and that it's to be expected.

I am not sure if I should be convinced by this explanation. This is my first LCD panel (having owned an iMac before) – but from what I've read, IPS Glow should disappear depending on angle, and should not have a withstanding effect on colors when the display is lit. Is that correct?

When the display is black, I don't notice any excessive glow or bleeding. But it bothers me that the colors are tinted when the display is showing white backgrounds.

Do you think that this is "just" IPS Glow, or a defect monitor?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is not caused by IPS glow. IPS glow is basically the shine of the backlight that shifts as you move your head around the display when it shows black or dark shades. It shows up only when viewed at an angle and it doesn't show up in pure white at all, unless you artificially reduce the contrast of the display down to a ridiculous value, for instance by using contrast adjustment in OSD or a brightness slider in graphics drivers, thereby starving the display of dynamic range.
*(IPS glow is an inherent flaw of IPS technology and is not to be confused with backlight bleed which depends on the way the plastic sheets in the monitor are fitted together and varies sample-to-sample)*

The actual problem you're having is called **lack of color uniformity.** It generally depends on your particular display sample, but it is known that some models are worse than others. For instance, some budget wide gamut monitors for professionals show a green tint on one half of the display and magenta on the other. And to be honest, your LG suffers from that particular issue. Unfortunately, it's all within the so-called *manufacturer's tolerance*, and that means that they don't care about color uniformity at all. They will tell you that "it's normal". You were simply unlucky.

The only thing one can do is simply return the monitor. Your case was particularly egregious: it's completely unusable and nobody should feel ashamed to return such a bad panel.